# Will tactical defending be optional?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 a new control system is included for defense, called ***tactical defending***.

It makes the constant pressing that was used a lot in FIFA 11 impossible by the fact that you now only *shield* the opponent player by holding the button, but don't rush into him. The actual tackle has to be done manually.

Also the second defender you can call now won't directly attack the ball carrier, but also just shields him and covers up additional passing routes.

This makes constant pressure play a lot harder and less automatic, which I think is a good thing, **but** tactical defending is only optional and can be turned back to the old mode in the control settings.

I would imagine that playing with the old mode against the new mode gives you an advantage in defending, because you still can put on constant pressure play without much manual effort.

#### So my question is:

Is there any information how this issue is going to be addressed in online play? Will online leagues restrict this in any way? Or is it just for everyone to pick?

I'm asking because I want to specialize in one of the defending modes (possibly the best), and therefore it will be good to know if the new tactical defending will be mandatory in online mode.

Comment: @the one who voted to close: Why do you think its not constructive? The value of the question is to find out if you can keep playing the "easier" legacy mode or if it has no future in competitive Fifa 12.

Comment: I really think it doesn't will be restricted because all specific gameplay settings, like 'Shoot Assistance' etc., were free to choose for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Romily Broad, EA's FIFA Community Manager, [tweeted the following](http://twitter.com/#!/RomilyBroad/status/114109114895966208):

> Tactical Defending: H2H Seasons, Clubs and Pro Ranked are locked to
>   TD. Legacy OR TD in Online Friendlies and Custom Unranked.

So if you plan on playing ranked matches then you should specialise in Tactical Defending.